# How to integrate the Qt libraries in SparxSystems Enterprise Architect

Tags: c++, qt, class-design, enterprise-architect

I like to know how one can integrate the Qt libraries into an Enterprise Architect project. I do not know if it is possible at all but I tried it with partial success:

I added a new package to my project tried to import qt through Context Menu / Code Engineering / Import Source Directory and started with the directory src/corelib/kernel. After adding quite a lot qt preprocessor macros to the EAs preprocessor macros list some classes were correctly imported but not all. E.g. I get errors on the Q_SIGNALS macro although I added it to EAs list.

Did anybody here tried that with success? And when yes can you give me some hints how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe Enterprise Architect's forum might be of help: http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turned to support@sparxsystems.com.au , their answer:

"Thank you for your enquiry.
No, unfortunately there is no easy way to integrate Enterprise Architect with Qt at this time.

With most frameworks, we typically recommend reverse engineering the framework into Enterprise Architect, allowing you to reference the classes / interfaces defined by the framework.

It sounds like the user in the link that you provided has already attempted this, but had difficulties due to the large number of Preprocessor macros used in this code.
Sorry we could not be of more assistance."

Maybe I can get your import package ?